# Make large ggmap map without running out of RAM

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

What is the best way to make a map of large extent and high resolution, preferably in ggmap, without running out of RAM?

Background:
I'm trying to make a large map of my city with ggmap. I say large because I want the map to be detailed enough that the saved pdf of it can be zoomed way in and street names can still be read. I think a zoom level of about 15 will accomplish that.

The problem is that I keep crashing my computer by running out of memory. Are there any secrets to getting something like this to work? The map I want to download has ~1100 tiles. I can get it downloaded and even plotted in R, but trying to save it crashes R. I could see doing it in pieces and then stitching it in something like photoshop, but this seems silly. It seems to me like ggmap (and ggplot2) are doing a lot of stuff in memory, and I'm wondering whether there is a way to write these files straight to disk.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: You can use `object.size` to estimate the size of an R object, and `memory.size` to see/maximize the amount of memory R uses on your system. You also might try piecing it together in parts, or use a cloud server.

Comment: Maybe you can plot your map directly to pdf with eg. CairoPDF? It helped me with ploting huge shp files.

Comment: @RScriv the idea of using a cloud server is a nice one. Thanks. I've sort of been pre-allocating memory for the tasks, but I just don't have enough memory with my current method to matter.

Comment: @Maciej thanks for this. I hadn't looked into CairoPDF yet. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two issues here:

1. *You're plotting a raster image with a low pixel density (so zooming in just gives you poor quality images).*

One solution is to use the ggsave() function in ggplot2 to output to scalar vector graphics (.svg).

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Create dummy data
y=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000,5),ncol=2))
paste(object.size(y)/1e6,"mB")

# Save to image file
image=ggplot(data=x,aes(x=X1,y=X2))+geom_point()

# Write image to file
ggsave(filename="test.svg",plot=image,width=10,height=8,units="cm")
```

If you don't want an .svg file, I'd stick to a .png file. You can look at the `res` attribute in `png()` [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html)

*2. You're plotting something very large all at once.*

This is where things get interesting. You could look at creating an image using a layered approach. That is: plot the polygons/lines/points from the large data set by their id/groupings (I'm not sure exactly how your data looks - hopefully this helps).
I've given a demo for some inspiration:

```
# Write to .svg
enter code here

# Make dummy data
test_data=data.frame(matrix(c(1,2.5,3,3,1.5,2,2,2,1,1,3,1,0,1),ncol=2))
test_data$id=c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b')

#Plot data
plot(c(1,2),c(3,3),xlim=c(0,4),ylim=c(0,4),pch=15,col='red')

#Plot layers in big dataframe
by(test_data[,c("X1","X2")],INDICES=test_data$id,polygon)
```

The by() function is very handy for producing multi-layer plots. It's significantly faster than a `for()` loop in R.

Comment: I was originally outputting as pdf, so I think I was skipping issues with raster graphics. This is good advice though. Also, the second part of your answer really helps! What I did before folks responded managed to "work", but my computer did have to be restarted afterwards and it took a LONG time to run.  I wrote the map directly to pdf with ggsave(), then loaded it in photoshop and had it scale the image up to poster size, then I output it as a jpg and the resulting image was both very detailed and small enough to distribute. Your solution looks better, I'm going to explore that now. Thanks!